# Non-parametric test for difference within and between groups

Tags: nonparametric, group-differences

I have a dataset that has three events: before, during and after. For each of these events there are five categories of rain: drought, dry, normal, wet and storm. For each of the categories there is a water level value. The water level data is non-parametric and the data is skewed. The categories are ordinal. What is the best test to use to look at the differences in medians within and between groups?

I have tried a friedman, but I don't know if it is the right test.

I'm using R.

This is an example of the data graphically. I'd like to see whether their is a significant difference within the categories (drought, dry etc.) and between the three events (before, during and after).

[image]

#### EDIT

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the data being non-parametric? Are they ordinal? Or skewed?

Comment: @DanielDostal see edited question.

Comment: Why is Friedmann not right? What about Mann-Whitney-U-Test?

Comment: @KaPy3141 Maybe its the wrong posthoc. But its only telling me differences between the events, rarther than each of the categories for each events. I've been following this: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_10.html and used the Exact Test for post hoc.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I would try to push it into some kind of regression. If the observations could be transformed into ordinal categories, then a proportional odds model might be very useful.

Comment: @DanielDostal do you mean how the data is laid out in the table I've just added?

Comment: You won't be able to use Friedman's test.  It simply won't be able to account for both *Time* and *Category* simultaneously.  More precisely, Friedman's test works only for data in an unreplicated complete block design.  ...  Aligned ranks transformation anova, as implemented in R, will work for your situation.

Comment: With the caveat that I wrote it, a short description and examples for ART Anova can be found here: [rcompanion.org/handbook/F_16.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_16.html) .

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thankyou!

Comment: @SalMangiafico I got this error after doing the art() model. Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model

Comment: It sounds like one of your independent variables is actually a reformulation of another independent variable.  See, for example, [www.statology.org/r-aliased-coefficients-in-the-model/](https://www.statology.org/r-aliased-coefficients-in-the-model/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138413/discussion-between-melanie-baker-and-sal-mangiafico).

Comment: What would you do for a “parametric” test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You won't be able to use Friedman's test. It simply won't be able to account for both *Time* and *Category* simultaneously. More precisely, Friedman's test works only for data in an unreplicated complete block design.
- There may be options to use a generalized linear model (GLM).  Or to fit a general linear model (LM) that won't be bothered by the heteroscedasticity in the model.  In R, using the *white.adjust* option in *car:Anova* may take care of the heteroscedasticity concerns.
- It sounds like aligned ranks transformation anova (ART anova), as implemented in R, will work for your situation.  But this approach is less flexible than using an appropriate GLM or LM.
- It's not clear to me if you have a repeated measures design.  In your study, if you have a variable for *Location*, where you measured the same Location - Before, During, and After - you would probably want to treat *Location* as a random effect in the model.